# Razor in .cshtml file - adding additional 'if' statements gives error

Tags: c#, razor

I'm trying to add a couple of if statements to a razor page.  The page I'm changing worked before the changes however when I add the blocks I've highlighted in the code sample below I get this error:

Error loading Razor Script ~/macroscripts/genericpage.cshtml
The code block is missing a closing "}" character. Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

```
if (publishedRightHandPods.Any())
{
    foreach(var rh in publishedRightHandPods)
    {   
        if (rh.image.GetType() == typeof(DynamicXml))
        {               
            if (rh.link.GetType() == typeof(DynamicXml))
            {
                var linkSupplied = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(rh.link.url) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rh.link.url);
                var titleSupplied = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(rh.title) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rh.title);

                @* *************** *@
                @* I'M ADDING THIS *@                   
                @* *************** *@

                @{
                  if (linkSupplied) {
                    <a href="@(rh.link.url)">
                  }
                }

                @* ****************** *@
                @* END OF ADDED BLOCK *@                    
                @* ****************** *@

                   <div class="side-pod" style="background: url('@(rh.image.mediaItem.Image.umbracoFile)') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; height: @(rh.image.mediaItem.Image.umbracoHeight)px">
                       @{
                           if (titleSupplied)
                           {
                               <h2 class="title" style="color: #@(rh.textColour);">@Html.Raw(rh.title.ToString())</h2>
                           }
                       }
                       @{
                           if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rh.linkText) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rh.linkText) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(rh.link.url) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rh.link.url))
                           {
                               <a class="findoutmore-btn" href="@(rh.link.url)">@(rh.linkText)</a>
                           }
                       }
                   </div>

                @* *************** *@
                @* I'M ADDING THIS *@                   
                @* *************** *@

                @{
                  if (linkSupplied) {
                    </a>">
                  }
                }

                @* ****************** *@
                @* END OF ADDED BLOCK *@                    
                @* ****************** *@

            }
      }
 }
```

I don't understand why the if statements inside the `<div>` are working however when I add the new (similar) statements outside the div I get the error.

****UPDATE****

If I remove the @{} surrounding the if statements that I added, like this:

```
if (linkSupplied) {
    <a href="@(rh.link.url)">
}
```

I see this on screen:

[image: The image you can see is the background applied to the div]

Comment: Have you tried with `<a href="@(rh.link.url)" />`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to open a HTML tag inside `if` statement but you don't want to close it, I suggest you to use `@Html.Raw()`:

`@if (linkSupplied) {
    @Html.Raw(string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">", rh.link.url))
}`

...then, when you close `A` tag...

`@if (linkSupplied) {
    @Html.Raw("</a>")
}`

Comment: Thanks, fixed now, although I still don't understand why Razor recognises the HTML as having to be outputted in the original code, however then fails to do the same for the added code

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand all your phrase but I try to respond you. Razor help you to keep HTML structure. Then when you open a HTLM tag with Razor, Razor wants to close it. Razor can't understand `if` conditions. Then, to avoid issues, Razor force you nest C# code and HTML tags together.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra apostrophe and greater then sign after the last closing tag in the second if statement:

```
@{
                  if (linkSupplied) {
                    </a>">
                  }
                }
```

Comment: Well spotted, although sorry Martijn that's a typo - the actual code doesn't have that

Answer (score 1):

try using global @{} rather than using it in every section. The markup will work fine inside the razor syntax. In this way you can simplify your code.

Comment: Thanks Sanjay, I tried that and added an update to the question to say that I was still getting the error